# MariaDB SQL error with query for wordpress

Tags: sql, mariadb

I meet a SQL error on MariaDB server and I don't understand why.

The SQL is:

```
 // Check if there is posts before our $date
    $postA =$wpdb->get_row("
SELECT ID, post_date 
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts 
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON
($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON
($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE   $wpdb->posts.post_status = IN ('publish', 'future')
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = 18
AND $wpdb->posts.post_date <'{$date}' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1");
```

and the error message is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IN ('publish') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND
>   wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy =' at line 7]

Comment: The syntax is `value IN ()` not `value = IN()` remove the `=`.

Answer (score 0):

This Syntax Error

> syntax to use near 'IN ('publish') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND
>   wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy =' at line 7]

would refer to this Part:

```
WHERE   $wpdb->posts.post_status = IN ('publish', 'future')
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
```

`$wpdb->posts.post_status` is a PHP Variable and could be empty that would lead to the invalid SQL Sentence resulting as:

```
WHERE IN ('publish') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy
```

Apart `IN('publish')` must go without `=`

Like:

```
WHERE wp_posts.post_status IN('publish')
```

Its very helpful in cases of SQL Syntax Errors to make the whole SQL Sentence displayed.

Comment: its a wrong syntax 

WHERE   $wpdb->posts.post_status = IN ('publish', 'future')

Comment: he just need to remove = before IN  as you can see in top comment.